# Swapping between Schedulers in Reactor

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a blocking workload that I want to execute on the bounded elastic scheduler. After this work is done, a lot of work that *could* be executed on the parallel scheduler follows, but it will automatically continue to run on the thread from the bounded elastic scheduler.

When is it "correct" to drop the previous scheduler you set earlier in the chain? Is there ever a reason to do so if it's not strictly necessary, because of thread starvation, for example?

I can switch the scheduler of a chain by "breaking" the existing chain with `flatMap`, `then`, `switchIfEmpty`, and probably a few more methods. Example:

```
public Mono<Void> mulpleSchedulers() {
    return blockingWorkload()
            .doOnSuccess(result -> log.info("Thread {}", Thread.currentThread().getName())) // Thread boundedElastic-1
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .flatMap(result -> Mono.just(result)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()))
            .doOnSuccess(result -> log.info("Thread {}", Thread.currentThread().getName())); // Thread parallel-1
}
```

Comment: why not just use publishOn() ?

Comment: I didn't know that was an alternative. Clearly, that's a far more ergonomic approach than my example. My question was in part fueled by how odd it felt to "break" the chain just to change the worker thread, but since publishOn clearly is meant to achieve the same thing, I guess there's no reason for me to _not_ just swap to the most appropriate Scheduler.

Comment: sure. It is not a bad practice to swtich schedulers throughout your reactive chain, but you should clearly know the reasons for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it is not a bad practice to switch the execution to another scheduler throughout your reactive chain.

To switch the execution to another scheduler in the middle of your chain you can use `publishOn()` operator. Then any subsequent operator call will be run on the supplied scheduler worker to such `publishOn()`.

[Take a look at 4.5.1 from reference](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers)

However, you should clearly know why do you do that. Is there any reason for this?

If you want to run some long computational process (some CPU-bound work), then it is recommended to execute it on `Schedulers.parallel()`

For making blocking calls it is recommended to use `Schedulers.boundedElastic()`

However, usually for making blocking calls we use `subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())` on "blocking publisher" directly.
[Wrapping blocking calls in reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking)